# Finding max consecutive 1 in a given array (leetcode)?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, stdvector

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(vector<int>& nums) {
        int ctr = 0, max = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++){
            if(nums[i]==1)
                    ctr++;
            if(nums[i] == 0 || i == (nums.size()-1))
                if(ctr > max){
                    max = ctr;
                    ctr = 0;
                }
        }
        if(max == 0)
            max = ctr;
        return max;
    }
};
```

this is my code and it is failing half test cases idk why?
i am counting the number of 1's  and if the element is zero then i am checking whether it is greater than max and storing it and if it is the end of array then check whether ctr is still greater and store it.

Answer (score 1):

In this if statement

```
        if(nums[i] == 0 || i == (nums.size()-1))
            if(ctr > max){
                max = ctr;
                ctr = 0;
            }
```

you have to set the variable `ctr` to `0` independent on whether `ctr` is greater than `max`. For example

```
        if(nums[i] == 0 || i == (nums.size()-1))
        {
            if(ctr > max){
                max = ctr;
            }
            ctr = 0;
        }
```

Also if the vector can contain other numbers apart from `0` and `1` then it will be safer to write the if statement like

```
        if(nums[i] != 1 || i == (nums.size()-1))
```

Pay attention to that this code snippet after the for loop

```
    if(max == 0)
        max = ctr;
```

is redundant  and may be removed.